# Preprocessor conditions in a template

Tags: c++, templates, c-preprocessor

I'm currently creating templates for a function and I need a method of not having the code inside the function if the template is in a specific class, I've tried what's below, but I didn't expect it to work, it's C++ and that's too convenient :P does anyone else have any suggestions on how I could achieve this?

```
template<typename T> int Position::lSetPosition(lua_State* L){
    #if T != Pro::Scene::Scene
        auto p = Util::luaP_touserdata<T>(L, 1);
        auto v = Math::Vector2(static_cast<int>(lua_tonumber(L, 2)),
            static_cast<int>(lua_tonumber(L, 3)));
        p->setPosition(v);
        return 0;
    #endif 
}
```

Comment: why don't you specialize the template to do nothing for Pro::Scene::Scene?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good place to use template specialization. Try out the following:

```
template<typename T> int Position::lSetPosition(lua_State* L) {
  auto p = Util::luaP_touserdata<T>(L, 1);
  auto v = Math::Vector2(static_cast<int>(lua_tonumber(L, 2)),
      static_cast<int>(lua_tonumber(L, 3)));
  p->setPosition(v);
  return 0;
}

template<> int Position::lSetPosition<Pro::Scene::Scene>(lua_State* L) {}
```

Essentially template specialization allows you to have different implementations of a template class or function based on its type, which is exactly what you want. For type `T` do something and for type `Pro::Scene::Scene` do something else. When the compiler sees what type you specify in your template, it will automatically choose the correct one to use.

Comment: Great solution - perhaps a little explanation of how and why this works?